# AutoCompleteTextView is not showing the result("text") from my SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview

Okay guys, i have an AutoCompleteTextView that is querying my db dinamycally via SimpleCursorAdapter to get the results that i want and set them into my AutoComplete,

okay i know there is a lot of posts here and tutorials on the internet and i followed them and try so many times get this thing done but i couldn't find a solution, so below is my code and a photo with actually is happening...

Here is the call method to my AutoCompleteTextView in my Form to pick the value...

```
AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.clienteACTV);
    actv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

    final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.clienteACTV };
    // String substring = nota_helper.getCliente();
    // Cursor managedCursor = dao.searchClientes(substring, substring);

    final String[] from = new String[] { "KUNNR" };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, null, from, to, SimpleCursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

    actv.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("KUNNR");
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    });

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence str) {
            String substring = null;

            if (str != null) {
                substring = str.toString();
            }

            //Cursor managedCursor = dao.searchClientes(substring, substring);
            Cursor managedCursor = dao.getCursor(substring);
            Log.d("0", "Query has " + managedCursor.getCount() + " rows of description for " + substring);
            return managedCursor;
        }
    });
```

And here is my query method in my db: If you guys need anymore code just let me know, and i update here...

```
public Cursor searchClientes(String substring, String index) {
    System.out.println("searchClientesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
    //return DBHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select *, rowid AS _id from " + TB_CLIENTE + " where KUNNR like '" + substring + "%';", null);

    return DBHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select KUNNR from " + TB_CLIENTE + " where KUNNR like '" + substring + "%';", null);

}
```

[image]

Comment: i thing text is displaying but not visible,try changing text color code.

Comment: what does logcat show for: Log.d("0", "Query has " + managedCursor.getCount() + " rows of description for " + substring); ? also try to use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor() to show the content of your Cursor

Comment: see this [link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html)

Comment: @krishnan his solution is more or less right,  contrary to link you posted with a TextWatcher and ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

[Here is your answer](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/)

change

```
final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.clienteACTV };
```

to

```
final static int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
```